# I am getting rows by a number of column's value

Tags: mysql, distinct

I want to get some posts by a keyword with search(LIKE) condition. I'm getting rows than I don't expect!

I tried DISTINCT but it didn't help, 
mysql5.7 x64,

```
SELECT DISTINCT ct.id,
                ct.cat_link,
                pt.post_id,
                lng_ct.cat_title,
                pt.post_title,
                pt.post_link,
                pt.post_content,
                pt.post_tags,
                pt.post_description,
                pt.post_author,
                pt.post_image,
                pt.post_date,
                pt.post_cat_id
FROM `cates_of_site` AS ct,
     en_posts_of_site AS pt,
     `en_cat_info` AS lng_ct,
     `en_subcates_of_site` AS sub_ct
WHERE (pt.post_description LIKE '%hello%'
       OR pt.post_tags LIKE '%hello%'
       OR pt.post_title LIKE '%hello%')
  AND ct.id = sub_ct.parent_id
  AND pt.post_cat_id = sub_ct.subcat_id
LIMIT 0,10
```

There is only one row in `en_posts_of_site` table. but I am getting 7 rows. why?

en_posts_of_site:

[image: en_posts_of_site]

en_subcates_of_site:

[image: en_subcates_of_site]

en_cat_info:

[image: en_cat_info]

cates_of_site:

[image: cates_of_site]

There is only one row in en_posts_of_site table. but I am getting 7 rows. why?

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, do not use legacy join syntax.  Furthermore, since you are joining all the table you are multiplying your result based on joined tables.

You need to use exists if you don't want your results to be multiplied. alternatively, you may consider to use `group by` for de-duplication. However, Exists will be more perform-ant.